# How to query a column of array type

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table `conditions` with a `trigger_values` column that is of type array and I want to query this table on the trigger_values and fetch the matching records.
For example, suppose my conditions table has 3 rows:

```
<Condition id: 1, trigger_values: [1, 2, 3]>,
<Condition id: 2, trigger_values: [2, 4]>,
<Condition id: 3, trigger_values: [3, 5, 7]>
```

and I have the query parameter `3`, I should get conditions 1 and 3 as their trigger_values columns contain `3`.
Basically, I want something like this:

```
Condition.where('trigger_values CONTAINS ?', query_value)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
Condition.where("'#{query_value}' = ANY(trigger_values)")
```

I needed to use [ANY](https://www.programiz.com/sql/any-all) command.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `IN` operator:

```
Condition.where('trigger_values IN (?)', query_value)
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what I am looking for. this will work in case my column contains a single value and I have an array as the query parameter.

Comment: I see your challenge now. Afaik SQL doesn't have an array type so it's probably not a good idea to store your column as an array. You should normalise your table (i.e. break your array elements into separate rows). If you can't do that for whatever reason, I think you need to handle this in your code (basically read the records and then in ruby parse them, which is not efficient but might be sufficient for small tables).

Answer (score -1):

You should use `Include` for array

```
params[:query_value] = 3

Condition.where('trigger_values IN (?)',params[:query_value])

<Condition id: 1, trigger_values: [1, 2, 3]>,<Condition id: 3, trigger_values: [3, 5, 7]>
```